# After updating tables in sql they rollback the following day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Everytime when I update the table rows in SQL Server, the update runs successfully and I also confirm and it shows that the rows were updated. However, the following day when I check I find that the updates I made have rolled back. I also checked if there are any transactions opened but there is none. I do not run my update statement in a transaction, therefore I do not have to commit any transaction after.
This is been happening for a while and it is really irritating.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see the updated values in **another instance** of SSMS? *(set the transaction isolation level for the other instance to Serializable with "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE")*

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your server or data access mechanism you're using (ie. ADO.NET) isn't configured to auto-commit transactions. [This MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) states;

> Autocommit mode is the default transaction management mode of the SQL
>   Server Database Engine. Every Transact-SQL statement is committed or
>   rolled back when it completes. If a statement completes successfully,
>   it is committed; if it encounters any error, it is rolled back. A
>   connection to an instance of the Database Engine operates in
>   autocommit mode whenever this default mode has not been overridden by
>   either explicit or implicit transactions. Autocommit mode is also the
>   default mode for ADO, OLE DB, ODBC, and DB-Library.

Try explicitly putting your UPDATE into a transaction and committing to see if that saves. Also ask your DBA to see if there is any setting on SQL Server that has change the default transaction management mode to set autocommit to false.